# C# question about: Do...While Loops (on Unity)

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine, crash

1. Why does `MyInt` being increased above 1 whereas the `while` condition is `false`?

```
public class HelloStackoverflow : MonoBehaviour {
    
    int myInt = 0;
    public bool myBool = false; 

    void Update () {
        
        print(myInt);
        do{
            myInt++;
        }while(myBool == true);

    }
}
```

-> I expected `myInt` to reach 1 and not more cause `myBool` is never set to `true`. I understood that the `Do` part of a `Do...While` is being executed at least once before the condition is being checked, to see if it should loop or not.

2. Then, why do the same code crashes when I set `myBool` to true from the Inspector?
   -> whereas I thought `myInt` would have reached 1 (Q1) and then would go further once (and not before) `myBool` was set to `true` from the Inspector.
3. Why do I feel so dumb just with this `Do...While` basic?

please excuse my english

Comment: If it was true unity would crash :) as endless loops in update so that very well. The answer below is correct however. It will get incremented each frame. So will go up fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

`Update` is called more than once. (Every frame, I think. I'm a Unity novice myself.) Every time `Update` is called, your `do...while` loop runs once, incrementing `myInt`. It crashes (or becomes unresponsive) when you set `myBool` to true because it never exits the loop.